# Как остановить программу и как лучше это сделать?

Tags: python-3.x

Программа делает так, чтобы строка на подобие "1???10?" превращалась в "1010101". Мне нужно, чтобы если все знаки являются вопросами и если длина строки не входит в ограничения, то программа должна останавливаться. Если это возможно, то оптимизировать так, чтобы это было читаемо новичку :p

```
ad=str(input())
if len(ad)<1 or len(ad)>100:
    print(f'Вы не вошли в ограничения')
    #Вставьте закрытие программы
if len(ad)==ad.count('?'):
    print(f'MANY')
    #Вставьте закрытие программы
que=False
while que is False:
    ad=(ad.replace('?0','10'))
    ad=(ad.replace('?1','01'))
    ad=(ad.replace('0?','01'))
    ad=(ad.replace('1?','10'))
    if ad.find('?') == -1:
        que=True
if ad.find('11')!=-1 or ad.find('00')!=-1:
    print(f'NO')
else:
    print(f'{ad}')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: а что вам, как новичку, не понятно в этом коде?

Comment: если будут способы оптимизации, то пусть будут читаемы. Я прекрасно могу понять, что здесь происходит

Comment: `while True:` и  `if ...: break`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто добавить блок `else` и программа сама выйдет в конце.

```
ad=str(input())
if len(ad)<1 or len(ad)>100:
    print(f'Вы не вошли в ограничения')
elif len(ad)==ad.count('?'):
    print(f'MANY')
else:
    while '?' in ad:
        ad=ad.replace('?0','10').replace('?1','01').replace('0?','01').replace('1?','10')
    if '11' in ad or '00' in ad:
        print(f'NO')
    else:
        print(ad)
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть различные способы, но самый надёжный - `sys.exit()`.
Разве что, для него надо сначало импортировать библиотеку `sys` с помощью `import sys`  .
Можно ещё запихнуть все в `def main():` и делать `return`, так даже быстреее работать, из-за специфики локальных переменных в питоне.
А вот `exit(0)` или `os.abort()` крайне **не рекомендую** использовать, ибо `exit(0)` работает через выдачу ошибки с кодом `0`, а `os.abort` нужен лищь для экстренного завершения.
**Итог: используйте sys.exit() или return**

Answer (score 0):

вызов функции `exit`, например

```
exit(0)
```

из любого места программы приведет к ее завершению

Comment: Не советую использовать эту функцию. Надежности ей явно не хватает, ибо сделана она была лишь для выхода из `python shell`

Comment: т.е. когда работают несколько потоков она не помогает? но в однопотоковом приложении должна корректно работать?

Comment: Имелась ввиду `sys.exit()`?

Comment: @Zhihar, функцию не стоит использовать совсем. Особенно на linux. Многие программы распознают этот выход как сигнал об ошибке. В частности это касается систем автопроверки и дебагеров.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше сделать функцию def
И чтобы остановить програму нужно вставить просто return